# How to send HTTP POST request which is of type "text/xml"

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to send the HTTP POST request which is of type "text/xml" Along with the request I am sending the Querystring value as :

```
"?wicket:interface=:9:XXOIForm:transactionForm:componentListPanel:componentListView:0:component:expressEntryContainer:expressEntry::IBehaviorListener:0:&wicket:pcxt=XXOIForm&random=0.48316250719134435"
```

Here are the few request headers I am adding manually

```
request.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-us,en;q=0.5");
request.Headers.Add("Wicket-Ajax", "true");
request.Headers.Add("Wicket-FocusedElementId", "id1a");
```

This all log I logged through the HTTP Anlayzer tool.

But I am not able to bypass this request. Please suggest me Is there is any way to send the HTTP POST request which is of type `"text/xml"`?

Or What I need to send in request headers?

Yes I am sending the post data in Byte Stream format only 
See I am having following code to send post data

```
protected void WritePostDataToRequest(string postData)
    {

        postData = postData.Replace("/", "%2F").Replace(",", "%2C").Replace(" ", "+").Replace("!", "%21").Replace("#", "%23");
        data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);
        request.ContentLength = data.Length;
        newStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        newStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        newStream.Close();
    }
```

Also I already added the request header content type.

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 3):

```
request.ContentType = 'text/xml';
```

Comment: +1 Yes, you need to specify the [`Content-Type`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Requests) header.

Comment: @veblin : thanx but I am having it in request headers already ..Still it is not working

Answer (score 1):

use byte stream to send ur data:

```
string data="wicket:interface=:9:eligibitiyBenefitsInquiryForm:transactionForm:componentListPanel:componentListView:0:component:expressEntryContainer:expressEntry::IBehaviorListener:0:&wicket:pcxt=EligibilityBenefitInquiryPage&random=0.48316250719134435"

byte[] dataStream = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);    
string uriStr = "www.abc.com";
HttpWebRequest rqst = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(Uri.EscapeUriString(uriStr));
rqst.KeepAlive = false;
rqst.Method = "POST";


rqst.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
rqst.ContentLength = dataStream.Length;
Stream newStream = rqst.GetRequestStream();

newStream.Write(dataStream, 0, dataStream.Length);
newStream.Close();
WebResponse resp = rqst.GetResponse();
```

Comment: I did as per your ans check my question (edited). Still it's not working

Comment: Before seding the request URL I mentioned above there are few more HTTP POST request of type XML, but only for this one I am not able to get response.

Comment: does it throws any exception?

Comment: possibly, you will need to process cookies. check the analyzer, does it have cookies?

Comment: looks like a json call. you will need to check whether it has:       Accept:application/json

Comment: @urlreader: I am passing all the cookies getting throught the Previous response as it is, there are Three cookies & I can see there is no change in cookie values.

Comment: there is `"request.Accept = "text/xml";"` No JSON Call